# Cant start supabase locally

Tags: docker, local, supabase, amazon-ecr

I have logged in and initialized supabase by following the guide for running supabase locally.

When i try to run `npx supabase start` i get this error:

> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for public.ecr.aws/supabase/postgres, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again.
>
> Retrying after 4s: public.ecr.aws/supabase/postgres:15.1.0.18
>
> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for public.ecr.aws/supabase/postgres, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again.
>
> Retrying after 8s: public.ecr.aws/supabase/postgres:15.1.0.18
>
> Error: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for public.ecr.aws/supabase/postgres, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again.
>
> Try rerunning the command with --debug to troubleshoot the error.

Running with --debug gives this information. (Removed jwt token), sorry for terrible formating :P

> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Sent Header: Host [docker]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Sent Header: User-Agent [Go-http-client/1.1]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Sent Header: Content-Length [312]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Sent Header: Content-Type [application/json]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Send Done
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Recv First Byte
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Sent Header: Host [docker]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Sent Header: User-Agent [Go-http-client/1.1]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Send Done
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Recv First Byte
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Sent Header: Host [docker]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Sent Header: User-Agent [Go-http-client/1.1]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Sent Header: Content-Length [0]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Sent Header: Content-Type [text/plain]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Sent Header: X-Registry-Auth [TOKEN]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:12 Send Done
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:14 Recv First Byte
>
> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for public.ecr.aws/supabase/postgres, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again.
>
> Retrying after 4s: public.ecr.aws/supabase/postgres:15.1.0.18
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:18 Sent Header: Host [docker]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:18 Sent Header: User-Agent [Go-http-client/1.1]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:18 Sent Header: Content-Length [0]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:18 Sent Header: Content-Type [text/plain]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:18 Sent Header: X-Registry-Auth [TOKEN]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:18 Send Done
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:20 Recv First Byte
>
> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for public.ecr.aws/supabase/postgres, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again.
>
> Retrying after 8s: public.ecr.aws/supabase/postgres:15.1.0.18
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:28 Sent Header: Host [docker]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:28 Sent Header: User-Agent [Go-http-client/1.1]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:28 Sent Header: Content-Length [0]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:28 Sent Header: Content-Type [text/plain]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:28 Sent Header: X-Registry-Auth [TOKEN]
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:28 Send Done
>
> 2023/07/14 23:31:30 Recv First Byte
>
> Error: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for public.ecr.aws/supabase/postgres, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: Your authorization token has expired. Reauthenticate and try again.

I tried running with --debug to get more information out.
Restarting computer and restarting docker

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have other public ecr repo login credentials.

`docker logout public.ecr.aws`

for example fixed similar issue i faced